please help me find the English/Hindi translations of some of the works of Appayya Dikshitar
Please provide the link of the Hindi or English translation of appayya Dikshitar's works related to Shiv and Devi.
Ex: Anand Lahari bhasya, durga Chandrakala stuti bhasya and shiv karnamrit

Koushik K one author is there. You can Check in kindle. He translated few works in English.
